# Reading select bytes in numeric values

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

We are receiving a single 32 bit integer value from a server

```
{
"value": -1072678909
}
```

In reality they have packed four separate 1 byte values into this one number so we need to read each byte separately to get its value. in this case...

*note: reading from right to left*

- The first byte is `00000011` (*e.g. value of 3*)
- The second byte is `00111000` (*e.g. value of 56*)
- The third byte is `00010000` (*e.g. value of 16*)
- The fourth byte is `11000000` (*e.g. value of 192*)

How can we accomplish this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy using bitshifting and masks:

```
var byte1 = val & 0xff;
var byte2 = (val>>8) & 0xff;
var byte3 = (val>>16) & 0xff;
var byte4 = (val>>24) & 0xff;
```

Comment: This works for 32 bit integers, when I try to translate to a 64 bit version I get invalid results. Is there a limit to how much JS can support? (*Ex. with 2251816993685505, expected to read 1 2 4 8. I changed the above to something like `(val >> 8) & 0xffff`).

Comment: Ok, but then your question changes to "how do I extract 4 short (2bytes) values from a 64bit integer", which is somewhat different. Javascript has no 64bit integer and values are stored as double precision floats. Bitshifting over this range is [not possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), so you may be better off just `bigValue.toString(16)` and hacking out the parts with string manipulation.